# OpenCV: How can i check the color of a roi?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a picture from which a region of interest is selected. Now I want to check if the color values ​​of the pixels are similar in both black and white and BGR. Return value should be true if and if not similar. How can I implement this with opencv in python?

```
def test(file, y1, y2, x1, x2):

    img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    white = (255, 255)  
    print(img.shape) 
    roi = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    print(np.all(video_place is white))
    cv2.imshow('image', roi)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

MfG Felix

Comment: Do you want exact similarity or some threshold-based comparison? If you want exact similarity, you could just do `np.all(img == white)`, using the `==` operator instead of `is`, since `is` checks that they are the same *object* instead of the same *values*. If you want threshold-based, then just take the absolute difference or the square difference with the color you want and sum that over the whole image. I.e. `np.sum(cv2.absdiff(img, white))` --- you can normalize by the number of pixels by dividing by `img.size`.

Comment: In the second case with `cv2.absdiff()`, the `white` argument would need to be the same size. You can of course do this with numpy directly instead of OpenCV to allow broadcasting, just be careful and make sure you're not overflowing.